# How do I add a button to the Android keyboard?

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I want to add a button to the panel that sits just above the Android keyboard.  This button will be used to generate some text and paste it into the active input.

I am not sure what the panel above the keyboard is called, so I have circled it in the picture below.

[image: android keyboard screenshot]

How do I add a button to this panel?

Comment: "I am not sure what the panel above the keyboard is called" -- it is part of the keyboard, most likely. The row above that looks like it is from the app. "How do I add a button to this panel?" -- you would need to write your own keyboard.

Comment: The buttons above the keyboard are not specific to this app (Samsung Notes).  It also appears on Messenger, Messages, Slack, etc.

Comment: "The buttons above the keyboard are not specific to this app (Samsung Notes)" -- in your screenshot, there are three rows above the QWERTY of the keyboard. The lowest is the number row, which is from the keyboard. The one that you circled is also from the keyboard, and to implement that, you need to implement a keyboard. The row above *that* looks like it is from the app, not the keyboard.